# How do I use ARCore with front camera of the phone

Tags: unity-game-engine, tango, arcore

I have been playing around with Google's AR-Core both in unity and android studio versions. Is there any way to replicate the AR experience using the front camera in android/unity sdk. After thorough research on arcore-android-sdk, I have found that the camera is internally evoked using the Tango library with the help of   *[TangoCameraIntrinsics](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/java/reference/TangoCameraIntrinsics)*.

Is there any work around for this in arcore-android-sdk or arcore-unity-sdk. Any leads would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/75) on the arcore-android-sdk, which was answered saying that *"ARCore currently doesn't work with the front camera"*

On a side note, Vuforia has the capability to use both the cameras for AR.